# How to make proper schema.org with many intentions using single page?

Tags: seo, schema.org, json-ld

I would like to know if there are possible solutions for this matter;

Currently I have a landing page that I want to put several intentions within a page.

1. Recommendation for best game 2022
2. Tips and tricks how to play a game
3. How-to about using our website tools
4. FAQ about our website

Is it possible to group each of those intentions into several nested script?
My aim is to make each of those topics recognize by search engine as separate intentions, I am afraid that if we include all of the topics within a single page, it makes the search engine confuse about our intention and decrease our chance appearing in search engine.

Or is it advisable just to separate each of those topics into several page so that the schema can be focused on each topic?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, look at your 5 main competitors in this niche, how they did it. Most likely it needs to be divided into different pages, but there are exceptions.

Comment: This does not provide an proper answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)